# MySQL last instance of in a group

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database table that contains multiple user photos. I am trying to write a query that will group by the subscriber_id but grab the latest entry.

For example:
A subscriber uploaded 4 photos. I need to group by the subscriber id but grab the latest photo uploaded. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Can you please post the table schema?

Comment: what does the table schema look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT subscriber_id, MAX(photo_id)
FROM user_photos
GROUP BY subscriber_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select photoId from photos where subscriber_id = ? order by date_added desc limit 1
```